# Mailgun routes not connecting to incoming controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailgun, bloc.io

I'm having a hard time finding a solution (almost 3 days) my code in *incoming_controller.rb* seems to be right, I tested it in the rails console and appears that the only problem is that when I send an email (from  my gmail account) to my mailgun email, the routes I declare won't connect with my rails app, and I get warnings in my mailgun logs.

What I'm trying to do is to allow users to send an email and convert the body content into a bookmark, and save it in the database, and the subject of the email as a topic.

Here is my **routes.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'welcome/about'

  root to: 'welcome#index'

  post :incoming, to: 'incoming#create'
end
```

My **incoming_controller.rb** file:

```
class IncomingController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:sender])
    @topic = Topic.find_by(title: params[:subject])

    @url = params["body-plain"]

  if @user.nil?
    @user = User.new(email: params[:sender], password: "temp0rary_passw0rd")
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    @user.save!
  end

  if @topic.nil?
    @topic = @user.topics.create(title: params[:subject])
  end

  @bookmark = @topic.bookmarks.create(url: @url)

  head 200
  end
end
```

*Topic belongs to User and has many bookmarks, User has many topics, Bookmark belongs to Topic.*

Also, here's my **mail.rb** file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  port:              587, 
  address:           'smtp.mailgun.org',
  user_name:         ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  password:          ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  domain:            'appfc266c436eb04ebaae05a3f3f8ad7e49.mailgun.org',
  authentication:    :plain,
  content_type:      'text/html'
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp

# Makes debugging *way* easier.
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

**Note:** mailgun works well with sending email confirmation instructions from Devise to the users, so it is configured correctly, what I can't do is to make mailgun to receive emails and store them in my rails db via parameters with the incoming_controller.

What am I doing wrong?

My mailgun route is as follows:

**Filter Expression:** catch_all()

**Actions:** forward("http://bookmark-this.herokuapp.com/incoming/")

Here's the warning logs I get in mailgun when I send an email:

[image: mailgun logs]

Here's the project repository on github: https://github.com/bntzio/bookmark-this

Many thanks!

Comment: what do the mailgun logs say when you send an email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailgun is receiving a `301` status code, being redirected to the `https` endpoint instead to the plain one. It seems that you have activated SSL but did not update the full route on the mailgun config to use it. You should update it to read like:

```
Actions: forward("https://bookmark-this.herokuapp.com/incoming/")
```